# Receiving Push Notification in Android Webview

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented a HTML5 app that uses [FCM Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) to receive push notifications. App works fine in all major browsers on desktop and mobile devices.

Now, I need to run this HTML5 app inside Android Webview. But, webview is not prompting for receiving push notification permission. And that can be the reason that app never receives push notifications.

Can anyone help, how can I force webview to show Notification permission?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to make this work automatically.  Android apps can only receive messages in their native Java/Kotlin code using the [documented integration instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).  The WebView component isn't able to receive messages directly because it's just an Android view component.  (I believe this is true for iOS as well.)

What you can do instead is receive the message natively, then proxy that data to the WebView when the app launches.  You'll have to inject the message data into the WebView by using a JavaScript bridge between native code and the WebView.  It's very much non-trivial to implement, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this now, I think, is if your app is a Progressive Web App (PWA), convert it to a Trusted Web Activity, then you can publish it to the google play store. I haven't looked into iOS yet, but I think it's possible to publish PWA's there too.

If you follow the video instructions below, be sure to not allow Google to digitally sign your app. If you want google to sign it for you, just put the Sha256 key from the google play console into the Google Asset Link tool on step 7.

[See this video for a simple walk through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDFjeMvxos&t=259s)